# App crashes with EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash, ios9

[image: EXC_SOFTWARE / UNCAUGHT_NS_EXCEPTION]
Unable to backtrace and this crash is only on iOS 9

Comment: Write some code instead of put only image here.

Comment: The name of the exception should be printed in the log. Please post it.

Comment: Also we would need to see the code you use for creating the cell views and data

Comment: try like this **Debug>Breakpoints>Create** **Exception** **Breakpoint..**, it will stop/break when this crash is occurred.

Comment: Thanks ALL, I am running on 5 devices on iOS 9 but i am not getting any crash